# How to use costum database table for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wpdb

how to use custom database table on custom posts in order to be able to use default wordpress functions (get_post and etc.), because I need to use external program to show competition's results (time and penalities in real time).

Comment: can you explain in more detail why you need to use a custom table (e.g, why post_meta wouldn't suffice)?

Comment: Because, as I have written before I using 3rd party external program that using it's tables which is impossible to change, and I need data, which entered from that program to connect to custom post type to show it by using default wp functions

Comment: there is still not enough detail in your question to understand what you are trying to achieve, hence, it is difficult to provide an useful answer.

Comment: I want for example to have competitions table in database and have competitions custom post type that  would use competitions table in databasse insted default wp posts table